# Old gym cement floor weeping water

Tags: concrete

The gym at my work suddenly started pooling water in spots that seem to have never been sealed or sealed properly. There is a wax top coat but in these spots of which there are many the cement is rough and pocked. This happened overnight. I think the floor was never properly finished. So one would have to strip down to the bare cement, seal then topcoat with some wax I believe. I have never worked with this kind of floor nor with the stripping. Any information or insight would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

[image: concrete weeping presumably]

Comment: That's a sign of hydrostatic pressure (from the ground below). You don't fix that with sealer.

Comment: Please revise to ask a more specific question. It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No sealer is going to be able to withstand the water pressure that is coming up through the slab.

Since taking the slab out and properly waterproofing below it and re-pouring it is probably a huge undertaking, your next best bet is going to be to find and eliminate the water source that is putting all this water under your slab.

Check your downspouts and foundation drains to make sure they are all unblocked and flowing away from the building.  If there are any pools of standing water on the property, remedy that.

Another thing you may have to do it to put a perimeter drain around the structure along with sump pump (or pumps) to get the groundwater out of the area.

While it would be nice to just slap some sort of paint on this and correct the problem, I don't think that's going to be a suitable option in this case.